# show data in modal with vueJS, does strange things

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog

I´m traying to show data en my modal with vueJS and Laravel. but when i clicked in my button to open modal and show data... my modal lose all shape.

[image]

is how duplicate form also don´t show correct the data. If i do click in other button to show other object....

[image]

i have a function in vue that i receive one parameter...

```
<tr v-for="data in datosAsistencia" :key="data.codAsistencia">
                <td>{{ data.codAsistencia }}</td>
                <td>{{ data.codContrato }}</td>
                <td>{{ data.fecha }}</td>
                <td>{{ data.mensaje }}</td>
                <td>{{ data.nombre }}</td>
                <td>
                    <select @change="cambiarEstado(data.codAsistencia, $event)">
                        <option value="0" selected>{{data.estado}}</option>
                        <option value="en_proceso">En proceso</option>
                        <option value="finalizada">Finalizada</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#create" @click="visualizar(data.codAsistencia)">Visualizar</a></td>
```

And my function vueJS. I want to do click in one button of my table and show this data belonging to one assistance and after show his actuations

```
visualizar: function(codAsistencia){

            this.visualizarActuaciones(codAsistencia);

            let url = "/getDatosAsistencia/"+ codAsistencia;
            axios
                .get(url)
                .then((response) => {
                    $("#datosAsistenciaModal").show();
                    $("#codAsistencia").val(response.data[0]["codAsistencia"]);
                    $("#fechaAsistencia").val(response.data[0]["fecha"]);
                    $("#mensajeAsistencia").append(response.data[0]["mensaje"]);
                    $("#usuario").val(response.data[0]["nombre"]);
                    $("#estado").val(response.data[0]["estado"]);
                    $("#bono").val(response.data[0]["tipo"]);
                    $("#tiempoContratado").val(response.data[0]["tiempoRestanteBono"]);
                    $("#codBono").val(response.data[0]["codBono"]);
                    $("#codContrato").val(response.data[0]["codContrato"]);

                    $("#tiempoRestanteBono").text(response.data[0]["tiempoRestanteBono"] + " Min");

                })
                .catch((error) => console.log(error));
        },
```

the funniest if i start to change in tabPane the one tab to other... finally, my modal show ok... I don´t know why pass this...

i hope anybody can help my please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve my problem. How do you say @JoeGalind, i have one for-each in my modal and jquery in response... Here it´s where all my data it´s duplicated... i removed my for-each

Answer (score 0):

You are using VueJS, but thinking as jQuery.  The beauty of VueJS is the model-binding, which automatically refreshes your data on the view.

Something like this should work for you. The data is bound to the v-model and updates automatically when assigning to the "selected" property I just declared.

```
<table>
<tr v-for="data in datosAsistencia" :key="data.codAsistencia">
    <td>{{ data.codAsistencia }}</td>
    <td>{{ data.codContrato }}</td>
    <td>{{ data.fecha }}</td>
    <td>{{ data.mensaje }}</td>
    <td>{{ data.nombre }}</td>
    <td>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#create" @click="visualizar(data.id)">Visualizar</a>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<div class="modal" v-if="selected">
    <label>Nombre</label>
    <input type="text" v-model="selected.nombre">
</div>
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            selected: null
        }
    },
    methods: {
        visualizar(id) => {
            let url = "/getDatosAsistencia/"+ id;
            axios
                .get(url)
                .then((response) => {
                    this.selected = response.data[0]
                }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```